# AWS Billing CUR - Surchage Value in lineItem/Operation

Tags: aws-billing

In the CUR Report , what does the value "Surcharge" means in the column LineItem/Operation ?

Have you ever seen this valie ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was related to dedicated instances provisioned in one of the accounts.
You can look at a column called lineitem/LineItemDescription or product/group and product/groupDescription for more information on the usage.

- Product: AmazonEC2
- Usage Type: DedicatedUsage